# TYPO3 Extbase/Fluid: Change SPLIT_PATTERN_SHORTHANDSYNTAX in StandaloneView

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

how to change the default SPLIT_PATTERN_SHORTHANDSYNTAX ({value}) by using the StandaloneView?

My Problem:
I have to render several LaTeX pages with different content. So I will use FLUID (Template/Partials). However there is the same Problem as in JS.... Is it possible to change the default "{value}" width ###value###???

The SPLIT_PATTERN_SHORTHANDSYNTAX static variable is defined in the TemplateParser.php but how can I change this dynamically by using a PHPView or StandaloneView?

Best regards Jürgen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do and a feature request to add this capability has been discussed and rejected. Please see https://github.com/TYPO3Fluid/Fluid/issues/106 for more information. Consider using CDATA wrapping to protect (parts of) your template from being processed as Fluid.